# "Erro" CRUD Hibernate JAVA

Tags: java, hibernate, crud, jee

Gente, estou começando a aprender a utilizar o hibernate e aconteceu uma especie de "error" ao persistir um registro. Ao cadastrar um objeto jogador devo também passar o time desse jogador, porém, o time já está cadastrado na base de dados, então eu só deveria passar o registro já existente até ai tudo bem, só que quando executo a persistência do jogador ele também persiste um time novamente.

Resumindo: Quando é cadastrado um jogador, ele também cadastra novamente o time que foi passado para esse jogador, mesmo o time já estando cadastrado na base de dados. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Classe Jogador:

```
public class Jogador {      
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "jogador_Cod")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="jogador_Nome", length=100,nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="jogador_DataNascimento" ,length=10,nullable=false)
    private String data_Nascimento;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="jogador_Salario")
    private double salario;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="jogador_Camisa")
    private int numeroCamisa;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="jogador_EmCampo")
    private boolean emCampo;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="jogador_cartaoAmarelo")
    private boolean cartaoAmarelo;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="jogador_qtdCartaoAmarelo")
    private int qtdCartaoAmarelo;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="jogador_qtdCartaoVermelho")
    private int qtdCartaoVermelho;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="time_Cod")    
    private Time time;`}
```

Classe Time:

```
public class Time {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="time_Cod")
private int id;

@Column(nullable=false,name="time_Nome",length=100)
private String nome;

@Column(nullable=false,name="time_Estado",length=100)
private String estado;

@Column(nullable=false,name="time_Pontos")
private int pontos;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="time")
private List<Jogador> jogadores;}
```

EDIT 1: Método da Persistencia

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                                    
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("conexaoDB");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();     
        try {
            et.begin();         
            //                  
            Time t = new Time();
            t.setEstado("PERNAMBUCO");
            t.setPontos(0);
            t.setNome("Sport Club do Recife");
            //
            Time t2 = new Time();
            t2.setEstado("SAO PAULO");
            t2.setPontos(0);
            t2.setNome("SANTOS");
            //
            Jogador j = new Jogador();
            j.setCartaoAmarelo(false);
            j.setData_Nascimento("29/02/9090");
            j.setEmCampo(false);
            j.setNome("Carlinhos Bala");
            j.setNumeroCamisa(10);
            j.setQtdCartaoAmarelo(3);
            j.setQtdCartaoVermelho(1);
            j.setSalario(1090);
            j.setTime(t);
            //
            em.persist(j);
            et.commit();                
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }       
}
```

Comment: Publique os métodos de persistência do jogador, @Junior

Comment: Adicionado Marcos, os 2 primeiros objetos times foram os que inseri no banco, como você pode ver, quando eu crio o objeto jogador eu apenas passo um time e ele acaba que persisti o registro novamente

Comment: Poste o erro que ocorre por favor.

Comment: Então Douglas, não é um erro em si, o problema é que, eu cadastrei os 2 times que estão na classe DadosFutebol, ao cadastrar o jogador eu passo um desses 2 times, até ai tudo bem, inclusive o registro é concluído, porem, ao inserir o jogador, mesmo se o time já estiver cadastrado na base de dados o proprio hibernate gera outro registro ou seja tenho 1. Sport 2. Sao Paulo, e ao registrar o jogador o hibernate inclui um novo, 3.Sao Paulo

Comment: Já tentou tirar o `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` do seu ManyToOne?

Comment: @Junior, nesse método vc não persiste nenhum `time`, vc só os instancia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse problema está acontecendo porque você não está passando a `Chave Primária` do seu `Time` que já está cadastrado.

Isso já resolveria seu problema:

```
Time t = new Time();
//Id do Pernambuco que é a chave primária
t.setId(1);
t.setNome("Pernambuco");
```

Porém note que se você passar um nome diferente do que consta no banco o mesmo será reescrito. Isso irá acontecer porque você está usando o `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` na sua relação com `Time`.

Recomendação:

Tire o `CascadeType.ALL` da sua relação com `Time` e coloque-o na relação com Jogadores:

Jogador:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="time_Cod")    
private Time time;
```

Time:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "time", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Jogador> jogadores;
```

Comment: oi, @DiegoAugusto, Ele está usando o `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY` para o `jogador`, logo não precisaria passar parâmetros pelo `setter`, não está ai o problema!

Comment: porém é estranho ele usar o `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY` para jogador e `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO` para `time`

Comment: @MarcosSousa Se ele quiser salvar um jogador com um time ele precisa setar o Id do time, pois se ele não setar como a relação será montada?

Comment: entendi, mas o código que vc colocou só está dizendo que o time "t"  tem o id = 1;
o código do método que ele publicou está correto, ele passa o time que ele quer persistir no `j.setTime(t);` ele diz que o jogador "j" tem um time "t", com todos os seus atributos incluindo o id. porém a ordem que ele persiste está incorreta, assim como a abertura da transação.

Comment: Ele passa um Time, mas não tem como saber qual time ao certo é, pois ele não passa a Chave Primária. Ele só passa um nome de time, dessa forma como a anotação do Time está como `CascadeType.ALL` e ele não passa um ID válido um novo time é criado com um novo ID

Comment: Concordo com vc em relação ao `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: vc simulou o exemplo?
irei refatora-lo e chegarei a uma conclusão mais fiel.

Comment: @MarcosSousa Sim. De inicio achei que o principal problema era o cascade, mas vi que era só um detalhe. Se ele não passar o id ele nunca irá persistir o time com os jogadores corretamente

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45175/discussion-between-marcos-sousa-and-diegoaugusto).

Comment: Galera muito obrigado, desculpem a demora do feedback mas só cheguei agora da faculdade, a resposta do Diego resolveu meu problema, era exatamente este o erro, foi mais um discuido do que um erro porque acabei esquecendo de passar também o ID. Muito obrigado mesmo a todos vocês!!